# How do I use a generic type on a function, where that type must satisfy certain conditions?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that clones an object or array, I want it to return the argument type but only accept objects and arrays.

How does one achieve this?

```
export function clone<T>(target: T): T {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(target))
}

// Should fail
clone('asdasd')

// Should pass
clone({})
clone([])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `extends` keyword can be useful to provide [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).

```js
export function clone<T extends any[] | object>(target: T): T {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(target));
}

// Invalid
clone("asdasd");

// Valid
clone({});
clone([]);
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzQGx2AB4AVOUGYFAEwGc4BDFATwG0BdOAHzggCMAVsAwA+ABQxGUAObAYALjikAlEvIBvAFBw4UeUii4AUgGUA8gDkAdGGl1g4s1et0YUTChmYELSdLkYFRUAbi0AXy0tAHpouABJFAA3RnxMGi0CInEAIkY6GnyaHNCo2LgANVT0zMIURw1w0qz68U5SoA)